# JQuery display problems?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to JQuery and was wondering how can I have `Changes saved!` displayed only once even if the user presses the submit button multiple times for example if a user decides to change there info three different times the text, `Changes saved!Changes saved!Changes saved!` is displayed i only want `Changes saved!` displayed once.

How can I fix this problem? What part of my code needs to be fixed?

Here is the JQuery code.

```
$(function() {
    $('#changes-saved').hide();
    $('.save-button').click(function() {
        $.post($('#contact-form').attr('action'), $('#contact-form').serialize(), function(html) {
            $('div.contact-info-form').html(html);
            $('#changes-saved').append('Changes saved!').show();
        });

        $('a').click(function () {
            $('#changes-saved').empty();
            $('#changes-saved').hide();
        });

        return false; // prevent normal submit
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the html using [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), this will replace the old value:

```
$('#changes-saved').html('Changes saved!').show();
```

`.append()` will add to what's there, `.html()` replaces it.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a span on the page with your "Changes saved!" blurb and initialize it as display:none

```
<span style="display:none" id="changes-saved">Changes Saved</span>
```

Then

```
$('#changes-saved').show();
```